# Need help before I even begin, having an image be displayed to multiple people

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ruby, html

I am looking into what language I would need to learn to do the following,

The screen needs to be view able by multiple people such as a map
First they would log in,
1 Person has control over the entire map including controls such as Fog of War, Place tokens down. 
1-5 People should be able to see the map but with out being able to make any changes to it.

Any help into the right direction would be helpful. If this does have a name in programming or what not, please let me know and I at least go do some research on it.

Comment: such as a multiplayer game? that'd be a search term to start with. "Building a javascript multiplayer game"

Comment: Perhaps you should start with 'hello world!' and then progress from there?

Comment: Do you know about sessions and all of that wonderful stuff?

Comment: Someone answered my question and yes I do know JavaScript, PHP, MySQL, HTML5, CSS and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable in a couple ways, but one newer technique/methodology that would fit well is [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). The basic idea is that users subscribe to various server feeds and receive updates when the server broadcasts new events.

In this way, Person 1 could send a request to the server to trigger placing a token on the map. Then the server would be set up to broadcast this event to all subscribers (People 2-5).

The glue would be some kind of client-side application you put together in Javascript that will handle the responses from the server and function as an application for the users. You would need to consider some means for controlling the difference between Person 1 and Person 2-5. That could be done via client-server setup where the client application depends on permissions and authentications from an application server.

You can accomplish the tasks in the last paragraph with any number of technologies, choose whatever feels most comfortable to you. If I were to do it, I might use backbone.js on the client-side and then some kind of RESTful API on the server side. RESTful is rather ubiquitous so just implement the server side in any language you prefer that has a 3rd party library support for Comet and REST.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for! I know a couple ways to make it happen, I could use like you said JavaScript, CSS, PHP and MySQL. Start two different pages where one has the controls to change and place conditions on the map. In turn it could just update the could update both pages. Thank you for your help!